# Request inside request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I have two systems, which are communicating with each other.

Ideal state:

1. SystemA makes `POST` to SystemB
2. SystemB is processing `create` action
3. SystemB needs update data in SystemA thus it makes `PUT` to SystemA
4. SystemA updates relevant data
5. SystemB finishes `create` action
6. SystemA receives `200` response

But the problem is, that SystemA is waiting for end of `POST` action and is not answering to `PUT` from SystemB. Result is that SystemA is TimedOut and then `PUT` is processed correctly.

What could be the best and elegant solution? Should I move the `POST` action to the background job? Should I create new Thread for it?

edit:
PUT is made via ActiveResorce and changes attribute of object in SystemA

Comment: you can use `sidekiq` to communicate between your 2 workers

Comment: What are the contents of the `PUT` call from SystemB to SystemA?

Comment: @mdlx: this is my first idea, I am just asking if there isn't some "realtime" solution :-)

Comment: @Simon I have expanded question a little

Comment: @Doktor the real time / blocking solution is constrained if the data of the `PUT` only exists on SystemB until the `PUT` is performed.

You have two choices, either you handle it asynchronously via a background worker or you return the data that's needed for the `PUT` inside your `POST` response and update the second resource inside the original `POST` call.

Comment: @Doktor Take into account that the second alternative I mention is highly discouraged, you have a secondary call which might fail due to timeouts, network errors, etc, which will make your first call fail. The proper way to handle anything that might not return immediately on an HTTP call is to defer it to a background worker.


P.S. Also, be more thorough in question descriptions, the more detail you give, the higher chance people will provide you with an accurate answer more or less tailored to your problem :)